# Using custom icons : '?' shows up

Tags: flutter, icons

I am implementing a custom Sign-in with Apple Button in my project. I went through these steps to use the custom icon:

1. Went to [this site](https://www.fluttericon.com) to get the icon and related dart files.
2. placed the dart file in lib folder, and the .ttf file in assets/icons
3. Here is my pubspec.yaml code:

```
  assets:
    - assets/

  // assets end, fonts begin

  fonts:
    - family: Custom
      fonts:
        - asset: icons/Appleicon.ttf
```

4. In the concerned page:
   `import 'package:project/appleicon_icons.dart' as CustomIcon;`
   Code for concerned Container:

```
Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                          color: Colors.black),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 9, 0, 9),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(CustomIcon.Appleicon.apple,
                                color: Colors.white),
                            SizedBox(width: 11),
                            Text(
                              "Continue with Apple",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  fontFamily: 'SF Pro'),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Output:

[image: Output image]

**Query:** How do i get the apple icon i chose instead of '?' box ?

**EDIT:** i tried using Ionicons plugin, which does have an apple icon. `Icon(Ionicons.logo_apple, color: Colors.white),`
i replaced the custom icon with this, yet same output. Why is that?

Comment: Have you tried using a Text instead of an Icon?

Comment: Can u give a code snippet as example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the full path to your icons TTF file.

I have my fonts inside **assets/fonts** and this is how i refer to my custom TTF:

```
assets:
 - assets/imgs/

fonts: 
- family: Toursy
  fonts: 
    - asset: assets/fonts/toursy.ttf
```

And they show up fine.

Comment: tried this, isn't working

Comment: Can you show the generated code by the custom icon site, the **appleicon_icons.dart**? I may have a hunch of what the problem is.